# Why is the output `True` in this python code is "print("gaa">"b")"

Tags: python, math

Does it depend on only first character?

Example:

```
print("aa">"bb")
False
print("aaajsdhfkjashdf">"bb")
False
print("c">"bbasdfsdfasdfasdf")
True
```

How does it work?

Comment: It's called [Lexicographical Order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

Comment: It looks for lexicographical order of alphabets one by one from left side.